# How to pivot or transform data in ArrayType format in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in following format:

```
|cust_id |card_num |balance|payment |due  |card_type|
|:-------|:--------|:------|:-------|:----|:------- |
|c1      |1234     |567    |344     |33   |A        |
|c1      |2345     |57     |44      |3    |B        |
|c2      |123      |561    |34      |39   |A        |
|c3      |345      |517    |914     |23   |C        |
|c3      |127      |56     |34      |32   |B        |
|c3      |347      |67     |344     |332  |B        |
```

I want it to be converted into following ArrayType.

```
|cust_id|card_num     |balance    |payment    |due        | card_type|
|:------|:--------    |:------    |:-------   |:----      |:----     |
|c1     |[1234,2345]  |[567,57]   |[344,44]   |[33,3]     |[A,B]     |
|c2     |[123]        |[561]      |[34]       |[39]       |[A]       |
|c3     |[345,127,347]|[517,56,67]|914,34,344]|[23,32,332]|[C,B,B]   |
```

How to write a generic code in pyspark to do this transformation and save it in csv format?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to group by `cust_id` column and use collect_list function to get array type aggregated columns.

```
df = # input
df.groupBy("cust_id").agg(
        collect_list("card_num").alias("card_num"),
        collect_list("balance").alias("balance"),
        collect_list("payment").alias("payment"),
        collect_list("due").alias("due"),
        collect_list("card_type").alias("card_type"))
```